# Difference between if (j%3 != 0 && j%4 != 0) and (!((j%3 == 0) && (j%4 == 0))), and why (!((j%3 == 0) || (j%4 == 0))) works if || means OR

Tags: c

I don't understand why the following syntax are not the same

```
if (j%3 != 0 && j%4 != 0)
if (!((j%3 == 0) && (j%4 == 0)))
```

Yet, the followings are.

```
if (j%3 != 0 && j%4 != 0) /
if (!((j%3 == 0) || (j%4 == 0)))
```

Why is that

```
!(A && B) != !A && !B
```

and

```
!(A || B) == !A && !B / !(A && B) == !A || !B
```

Comment: This isn't a syntax thing; it is a boolean logic thing. `a && b` is equivalent to `!(!a || !b)` . In both cases, the overall expression is true only if both `a` and `b` are true.

Comment: De Morgans law :https://www.vedantu.com/maths/de-morgans-first-law

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about Boolean algebra not C programming. C follows [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 3):

This is the mathematic boolean logic.

```
A and B <=> not (not A or not B)

not A and not B <=> not (A or B)

not (A and B) <=> not A or not B
```

For proving these equations, use value tables.

```
0 & 0 = 0   !(1 | 1) = !1 = 0
0 & 1 = 0   !(1 | 0) = !1 = 0
1 & 0 = 0   !(0 | 1) = !1 = 0
1 & 1 = 1   !(0 | 0) = !0 = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Say I have a red car and grey house, then "my car is blue and my house is grey" is false (`!(A && B)`). Yet "my car isn't blue and my house isn't grey" is also false (`!(!A && !B)`). So `!(A && B)` and `!A && !B` clearly aren't equivalent.

The actual negation of "my car is blue and my house is grey" is "my car isn't blue or my house isn't grey" (`!A || !B`).

We can also clearly see this is the case by plugging all possible values into the equations.

| A | B | !(A && B) | !A || !B | !(A || B) | !A && !B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | !(0 && 0) = !0 = 1 | !0 || !0 = 1 || 1 = 1 | !(0 || 0) = !0 = 1 | !0 && !0 = 1 && 1 = 1 |
| 0 | 1 | !(0 && 1) = !0 = 1 | !0 || !1 = 1 || 0 = 1 | !(0 || 1) = !1 = 0 | !0 && !1 = 1 && 0 = 0 |
| 1 | 0 | !(1 && 0) = !0 = 1 | !1 || !0 = 0 || 1 = 1 | !(1 || 0) = !1 = 0 | !1 && !0 = 0 && 1 = 0 |
| 1 | 1 | !(1 && 1) = !1 = 0 | !1 || !1 = 0 || 0 = 0 | !(1 || 1) = !1 = 0 | !1 && !1 = 0 && 0 = 0 |

Two equivalences that are identified by the above table:

```
!(A && B) = !A || !B
!(A || B) = !A && !B
```

These are known as [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: Brilliant truth-table.